# ignore certain word from gate nlp NER

Tags: nlp, gate

I want to add ignore.lst in gate annie gazetteer so that the word in that list does not show while using NE. I see stop.lst inside annie gazetteer. What is the use of stop.lst for? I created ignore.lst and added it to list.def. How to make gate nlp not show names contain in ignore.lst?

Answer (score 0):

I don't that it will work using only gazetteers. I think that the option will be to write a post-processing "cleanup" JAPE rule, which will delete all NE, which contains words from your stoplist.